# Replacing data with range-v3

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, range-v3

## TL;DR

How is it possible to obtain the same results of

```
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));
```

using range-v3, and possibly its nice syntax?

**EDIT**

The reason I was having troubles is the misunderstanding of how to correctly use `ranges::copy`: the second argument must be an **iterator**, not a *range* object. My fault ;)

Nevertheless, I am still asking if some sort of syntactic sugar is available to perform a *ranged assignment*, like the following:

```
ranges::???(b) = a | op1 | op2 | ... ;
```

## The problem

I have got two fixed size vectors (at runtime). I need to perform some *complex* transformation of the data in the first vector and store the results in the second vector. I need to keep the first vector and I do not want to create a new temporary vector.

#### Common code

```
using namespace std;
vector<double> a;
...
vector<double> b(a.size());
```

#### With std

```
transform(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), complexFun);
```

#### Hybrid std-rangev3

```
auto transformation = a | ranges::view::transform(complexFun);
copy(begin(transformation), end(transformation), begin(b));
```

In this simple case, it is a bit unnecessary to do so. However, if more than one operation is involved, creating the range view then using `std::copy` is particularly useful.

#### What I would like to write

```
ranges::???(b) = a | ranges::view::transform(complexFun);
```

What I am expecting is that this feature already exists, and I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
ranges::transform(a, b.begin(), complexfun);
```

?

EDIT:
... or maybe

```
ranges::copy( a | ranges::views::transform(complexFun), begin(b) );
```

?

Comment: What if I would like to use multiple views? Silly thing: transforming a with complexFun, then adding the index (using iota) to the result and storing to b?

Comment: Ok, I just got my conceptual error: I was trying to use "b" as second argument of ranges::copy, instead of using begin(b). If you want to say that this was the problem, I will accept your answer. Nevertheless, is there any syntactic sugar to avoid ranges::copy and "assign" a lazy view to an output range?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of good ways to do this. First, if you don't yet have the destination `vector` and you want to create it:

```
auto b = a | ranges::view::transform(complexFun) | ranges::to_vector;
```

Second, if you already have a destination `vector` whose capacity you want to reuse:

```
b.clear(); // Assuming b already contains junk
b |= ranges::action::push_back(a | ranges::view::transform(complexFun));
```

In both cases, range-v3 is smart enough to reserve capacity in the destination vector for `ranges::size(a | ranges::view::transform(complexFun))` elements to avoid copies due to reallocation.

Comment: It is not an ideal situation: you are paying the price of incrementing the size of b for every push. The solution I am searching for must be equivalent to the hybrid case, with zero overhead.

Comment: @dodomorandi have you read the last paragraph? It tells you that `b` will be reserved in advanced and no reallocation will occur.

Comment: @bolov as I said, you do not have any allocation, but you are still manipulating the counter for the number of objects. It is a very small price to pay, but it is still more than necessary in this case.

Comment: @bolov right, I was forgetting about a **huge** amount of optimization misses using `push`. Good vectorization is one of these. If you don't believe me, [just measure it](http://quick-bench.com/xYi8cKN0bSTk7moCmcG0janDdig).

Comment: `ranges::action::push_back(v, r)`, when `r` is a range, is implemented with `v.insert(v.end(), begin(r), end(r))`. This should be vectorize-able if your STL implementation is worth its salt.